# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver when running Sonar against Maven project on Jenkins

Tags: sonarqube, jenkins-plugins

I've installed Sonar 1.8 plugin to Jenkins, according to the instructions form the official site, but build fails with the exception: `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver`

There are no dependencies to the Sonar or MySql in the pom.xml. It was working with default settings (Derby DB), but fails with MySql.

I've created CLASSPATH system env var pointing to `c:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Connector J\mysql-connector-java-5.1.20-bin.jar` but the exception still occurs.

Any ideas how to fix this? Maybe I need to configure each job by setting some system properties to point to the jar file location?

Comment: It was installed as a Windows service, the same issue with Oracle Driver (java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was just to comment Derby settings and uncomment MySql settings in sonar.properties :)